# Postgres - Why is the temporary table created in one function undefined in another function?

Tags: postgresql, function, temp-tables

this is a Postgres related question.

I can't figure out why I get `ERROR undefined_table relation "temp_table" does not exist`

I tried all sorts of things, but maybe I don't really understand how I correctly use a temporary table in a function that was created in another function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION api.test() RETURNS BOOLEAN LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER AS $$
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table( id INT NOT NULL) ON COMMIT DROP;
    INSERT INTO temp_table (id) VALUES (1), (2);
    RETURN TRUE;
END;
$$;

CREATE FUNCTION api.test_id(p_id INT) RETURNS BOOLEAN LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER AS $$
DECLARE
    v_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO v_id FROM temp_table WHERE id = p_id LIMIT 1;
    return v_id IS NOT NULL;
END;
$$;
```

PS: I create the temporary table in a function to protect it from being accessed outside of the functions by a different role.

Comment: You probably call the two functions in different transactions. Note the `ON COMMIT DROP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code. It works if in the same transaction.

You are working from different transactions. See here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-COMPATIBILITY

At "Temporary Tables"

Comment: are you able to show me how you get it to work? I tried to put `begin` and `commit` around the commands but still get the same error. See here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pBadrfiEhbR3wqXbryWDwR/0

Comment: Here you are: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3KD5bYbuzguNjhEMoTMazP/0